# Esitimation about a holder continous function minus a linear function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose a Holder function $f(x)$ satisfies $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |x-y|^{\alpha},\forall x,y\in [a,b]$$
where $\alpha\in (0,1]$. 
$\phi$ is a linear function satifying $$\phi(a) = f(a),\phi(b) = f(b)$$

Is it true that$|f(x)-\phi(x)|\leq |b-a|^{\alpha}, \forall x\in [a,b]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you work out what $\phi$ is you see that $$f(x)-\phi(x)=\frac{b-x}{b-a}(f(x)-f(a))+\frac{x-a}{b-a}(f(x)-f(b)).$$Since both coefficients are positive it follows that$$\begin{align}|f(x)-\phi(x)|\le&=\frac{b-x}{b-a}|f(x)-f(a)|+\frac{x-a}{b-a}|f(x)-f(b)|\\&\le \frac{b-x}{b-a}|x-a|^\alpha+\frac{x-a}{b-a}|x-b|^\alpha\\&\le \frac{b-x}{b-a}|b-a|^\alpha+\frac{x-a}{b-a}|a-b|^\alpha\\&=(b-a)^\alpha.\end{align}$$

**Note.** At first I assumed this was going to use the convexity of the function $-t^\alpha$ on $[0,\infty)$. But no, the same argument shows that

> > If $h:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ is non-decreasing and $|f(t)-f(s)|\le h(|t-s|)$ then $|f(x)-\phi(x)|\le h(b-a)$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about $\vert f(x)-\phi(x)\vert \leq \vert b-a\vert^\alpha$, but I think you can show that $\vert f(x)-\phi(x)\vert \leq 2\vert b-a\vert^\alpha$ if it helps. $\phi$ has to be: 
$$ \phi(x)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-a)+f(b) $$

You can therefore write:

$$ f(x)-\phi(x)= f(x)-f(b)+ \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-a) $$

And by the triangle inequality:

$$ \vert f(x)-\phi(x)\vert \leq \vert f(x)-f(b)\vert+ \vert f(b)-f(a)\vert \cdot \Big\vert \frac{x-a}{b-a} \Big\vert\leq $$

$$ \leq \vert x-b\vert^\alpha+ \vert b-a\vert^\alpha \cdot \Big\vert \frac{x-a}{b-a} \Big\vert $$

$ \Big\vert \frac{x-a}{b-a} \Big\vert\leq 1 $ and $\vert x-b\vert^\alpha \leq \vert a-b\vert^\alpha$, which means that:

$$ \vert f(x)-\phi(x)\vert \leq 2\vert a-b\vert^\alpha  $$